# How to define a global logger variable in Python

Tags: python, logging

I would like to have a Python module that can be used as a module, or a CLI, and I want to
define a global logger that I can access from other module.

Here is my logger.py file

```
import logging
def set_logger():
    logging.basicConfig(filename='zzz.log', level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='w')  
    logging.info("start logging")
    return logging.getLogger()

CGLogger = set_logger()
```

and in my toplevel `mymodule/__init__.py` I have:

```
from mymodule.logger import CGLogger
```

then I would like to do:

```
from mymodule import CGLogger

CGLogger.info("blah")
```

Unfortunately, nothing happens, `zzz.log` is not even created.

Initially, I didn't have the `set_logger` function, and had its code directly in `logger.py` and having `CGLogger = logging.getLogger("mylogger")`, but this does not work either

What puzzled me, is that when I use the debugger, I go through these lines and even the `logging.info(...)` calls does nothing.

I run the debugger while testing with `pytest`.

Comment: I edited my example a bit. I can't guarentee it, but I guess that should be a working example to understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding how the logging module works.

In your modules you want to use later on you just initialize a logger and write the messages.

In the main application you can configure all the loggers and define the handlers.

Let's say you have a package foo with just an `__init__.py` and your `module.py`.

Your init could be empty. And your module could look like this.

```
from logging import getLogger


logger = getLogger(__name__)

def test():
    logger.info("it simply works")
```

Then in your application you use it like:

```
import logging
import logging.config
from foo import module

logger = logging.getLogger("main_logger")

config_dict = {
    "version": 1
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
        }
    },
    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "class": logging.FileHandler,
            "level": DEBUG,
            "formatter": simple,
            "file": " test.log"
        }
    },
    "loggers": {
        "foo.module": {
            "level": DEBUG,
            "handlers": [file],
            "propagate": False
         },
         "main_logger": {
            "level": DEBUG,
            "handlers": [file],
            "propagate": False
         }
    }
}

logging.config.dictConfig(config_dict)

logger.info("starting")
module.test()
```

Configs can become huge and complicated. You can look it up in docs. Important is that you can define in the config that you want the logger from foo.module via 'foo.module', since we instanced it via `__name__`.

Answer (score 1):

The author of the logging module had your idea first! `logging.getLogger()` just looks up a dictionary in the logging module. Therefore, all loggers are effectively globally accessible. `basicConfig` configures a handler on the `root` logger. That, with no other handlers, will capture logs from all loggers you might define. But, none of this is really your issue.

You're probably getting caught out by pytest. Put a `1/0` just above your basicConfig call to see if it's even being reached. (You could put a break point and run in debug but, sometimes, I like the confidence and assurance only a ZeroDivisionError can provide. `print` maybe ignored if using pytest so not a good idea for debugging)

Try putting your basicConfig in `conftest.py`, just that line, no function. Then use `logging.getLogger()` where ever you like elsewhere. (I would actually recommend `logging.getLogger(__name__)`)

Finally, calling the function each time you want the logger is misleading. You're invoking basicConfig each time. Some might think it's initialising the log file each time. Other's know the basicConfig is a no-op when called again. Either way, it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='zzz.log', level=logging.DEBUG, filemode='w')  
logging.info("start logging")


CGLogger = logging.getLogger()
```

and use it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The reason I wanted to have that global variable, is that I may have two apps running my script:

- one is a python script (the *main*), called as command in shell/dos/...
- one is from a tool embedding python, in which I can import my module

Therefore, I wanted to initialize my logging in some common place. All the comments provided are correct of course, with the logging configuration and *getLogger*. But...

I finally went into the `logging.basicConfig()` code, where I discovered that the function **does nothing** if some handlers are already present (well, actually this is in the doc... RTFM)

This is the case with `pytest`, since it also captures the log. The `logging.basicConfig()` is then inoperant. To get the log:

- add `caplog` as a parameter of the test to get the captured logging
- or, use `pytest.ini` (or other configuration) with:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = true
log_cli_level = INFO
```

This tells to send any logging to the console (I'm using VS), and set the level of course (see [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-log_cli) doc for all details)

Of course, I don't have my log file from the `logging.basicConfig()`call, but I have the results in the console. I could have the file by adding *force=True*, but our tool embeds Python < 3.8, and the option does not exist.

Running my app out of `pytest` works also like a charm, and I got my log file.